# Subtract rows in R dataframes by dates

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a  dataframe, `df`, like this one:

```
           Date Colombia    Chile
2015-01-01  2015 38.12333 31.92088
2020-01-01  2020 44.95952 38.10776
```

And I would like to substract the 2015 values, for each country, from the values in 2020, so I could get a new dataframe looking loke this one:

```
           Date Colombia    Chile
2020-01-01  2020 6.83619    6.18688
```

But I would like to do it by dates, i.e, the identifier is that the value of the lower date is subtracted from the value of the higher date in each country.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: `library(dplyr)` and `df %>% mutate(across(Colombia:Chile,  ~ .x - lag(.x)))`

Comment: Thanks, this does not work, it just gives the original dataframe:                            Fecha Colombia    Chile
2015-01-01  2015 38.12333 31.92088
2020-01-01  2020 44.95952 38.10776

Comment: `df <- df %>% mutate(across(Colombia:Chile,  ~ .x - lag(.x)))`

Comment: Unfortunately, I keep getting the same result and I don't know how to get what I need. Can you please help me?

Comment: A reproducible example would be helpful for identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff(as.matrix(df))
           Date Colombia   Chile
2020-01-01    5  6.83619 6.18688
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error: Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator. Also, in your answer the date 2020, does not appear. Can you help me please?

Comment: @ValeriaArango 2020-2015 = 5. Note that all the elements in your dataframe should be numeric